# Check if a word is combo of some given symbols

Tags: php, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an array of symbols (not only characters, but also syllables, such as 'p', 'pa', etc.) and I'm trying to come up with a good algorithm to identify words that can be created by concatenating those symbols.

e.g. given the array of symbols `('p', 'pa', 'aw')`, the string `'paw'` would be a positive match.

This is my current implementation (too slow):

```
function isValidWord($word,&$symbols){
    $nodes = array($word);
    while (count($nodes)>0){
        $node = array_shift($nodes);
        $nodeExpansions = array();
        $nodeLength = strlen($node);
        if (in_array($node,$symbols)) { return true; }
        for ($len=$nodeLength-1;$len>0;$len--){
            if (in_array(substr($node, 0, $len), $symbols)){
                $nodeExpansions[] = substr($node, $len-$nodeLength);
            }
        }
        $nodes = array_merge($nodeExpansions,$nodes);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't seem like a difficult problem, it's just a depth-first search implementation on an acyclic? tree, but I'm struggling to come up with an implementation which is both memory and CPU efficient. Where can I find resources to learn about this kind of problem?

Also, here is a link to a script for testing it and comparing it to the solutions proposed in the comments below: http://ideone.com/zQ9Cie

And here [an album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScMil.jpg) showing captures of really odd results: How can my current iterative method be 12x faster than the recursive one (proposed by @Waleed Khan) when I run them on my dev server, but 2x slower when I run them on my production server, considering both servers have almost identical configurations? (One is an EC2 micro instance and the other a VirtualBox container, but they both have the same OS, config, updates, PHP version and config, number of cores and available RAM)

Comment: Can you reuse symbols?

Comment: yes, no problem with that

Comment: All trees are acyclic. This is just depth-first search on a tree. http://ideone.com/56eSWS

Comment: You could always transform the symbols into a regex and see if it matches using `preg_match` or whatever; so you'd check 'paw' against `(p|pa|aw)*`.

Comment: @Waleed Khan Definitely what I was looking for. Please post it as an answer so I can upvote and accept :-)

Comment: Forget my previous comment: Regex are shockingly fast; Unfortunately after more extensive testing I've found out there are some cases of use where the resulting regex is too long and won't compile :-( The search function suggestion you've linked was my first idea too but it was too slow. Then I came up with an iterative version of it, hoping to make it faster by avoiding recursion. It made it 12x faster but it's still too slow... I've added to my question an ideone link to my test script code to give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve: http://ideone.com/jgzzwa

Comment: The given script shows the iterative method at 0.008s and the recursive method at 0.004s, so I'm not sure how it's faster to do the former.

Comment: Maybe you could compile PCRE to handle larger regexes? http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/531519-preg_match-compilation-failed-regular-expression-too-large suggest the `PCRE_CONFIG_LINK_SIZE` option could be increased from `2` to `4` which would allow larger regexes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, maybe it'll work :-) About the recursive method beating the iterative, that's pretty curious: As the number of symbols in the word to test increases, the iterative method should be faster, or at least more memory efficient. I did verify it on my development server: The iterative version ran consistently faster: about 12x faster every time (Check pic1 on this album: http://imgur.com/a/51IeS).

Comment: I didn't notice it was running slower on ideone, but now you've pointed it out I did retest and still got the same 12x faster results (pic2: http://imgur.com/a/51IeS) on my dev server, but not on my production server (pic3: http://imgur.com/a/51IeS). This is really weird because, despite one being a VirtualBox machine and the other an EC2 instance, they have exactly the same configurations (OS and PHP version, config and updates, as well as available RAM and number of virtual cores)

Comment: BTW: You'll see that in the first screen capture the exec times on the first test are considerably higher: ~320 seconds for the iterative and ~25 seconds for the recursive. That's because on that test I was using the ~10000 symbols dictionary (The one that breaks the regex; that's also why there's no regex result).

Comment: Right now we're doing a linear search through the array of 10,000 elements, which means 10,000 comparisons per loop. You could make a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)-like structure to drastically speed up the search; then we directly access only the possible continuations, which would probably be a major improvement.

Comment: I see your point. I'm about to try that :-)

Comment: @Waleed Khan It wasn't working at first and it took me a while to find the time again to do it right but I've finally tried the trie structure. Not much of an improvement: http://ideone.com/zQ9Cie (Maybe I've implemented it wrong?)

Comment: (Still need to try it on a much larger dictionary, though)

Comment: Yep, with the kind of dictionary I want to use the difference is huge. I've posted an answer with some results on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Waleed Khan suggested, I've tried improving my algorithm using a Trie structure for the dictionary instead of a plain array to speed up the search for matches.

```
function generateTrie(&$dictionary){

    if (is_string($dictionary)){
        $dictionary = array($dictionary);
    }
    if (!is_array($dictionary)){
        throw new Exception(
            "Invalid input argument for \$dictionary (must be array)",
            500
        );
    }

    $trie = array();

    $dictionaryCount = count($dictionary);
    $f = false;
    for ($i=0;$i<$dictionaryCount;$i++){
        $word = $dictionary[$i];
        if ($f&&!inTrie('in',$trie)){
            var_export($trie);
            exit;
        }
        if (!is_string($word)){
            throw new Exception(
                "Invalid input argument for \$word (must be string)",
                500
            );
        }
        $wordLength = strlen($word);
        $subTrie = &$trie;
        for ($j=1;$j<$wordLength;$j++){
            if (array_key_exists($subWord = substr($word,0,$j),$subTrie)){
                $subTrie = &$subTrie[$subWord];
            }
        }
        if (array_key_exists($word,$subTrie)){
            continue;
        } 
        $keys = array_keys($subTrie);
        if (!array_key_exists($word,$subTrie)) {
            $subTrie[$word] = array();
        }
        foreach ($keys as $testWordForPrefix){
            if (substr($testWordForPrefix,0,$wordLength) === $word){
                $subTrie[$word][$testWordForPrefix] = &$subTrie[$testWordForPrefix];
                unset($subTrie[$testWordForPrefix]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $trie;

}

/**
 * Checks if word is on dictionary trie
 */
function inTrie($word, &$trie){

    $wordLen = strlen($word);
    $node = &$trie;
    $found = false;
    for ($i=1;$i<=$wordLen;$i++){
        $index = substr($word,0,$i);
        if (isset($node[$index])){
            $node = &$node[$index];
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $found = false;
        }
    }

    return $found;

}
/**
 * Checks if a $word is a concatenation of valid $symbols using inTrie()
 * 
 * E.g. `$word = 'paw'`, `$symbols = array('p', 'pa', 'aw')` would return
 * true, because `$word = 'p'.'aw'`
 *
 */
function isValidTrieWord($word,&$trie){
    $nodes = array($word);
    while (count($nodes)>0){
        $node = array_shift($nodes);
        if (inTrie($node,$trie)) { return true; }
        $nodeExpansions = array();
        $nodeLength = strlen($node);
        for ($len=$nodeLength-1;$len>0;$len--){
            if (inTrie(substr($node, 0, $len), $trie)){
                $nodeExpansions[] = substr($node, $len-$nodeLength);
            }
        }
        $nodes = array_merge($nodeExpansions,$nodes);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't make much of a difference for small dictionary sizes (where preg_match is still the fastest implementation by several orders of magnitude), but for medium sized dictionaries (~10000 symbols) where longer symbols are usually a combination of shorter ones (which is where preg breaks and the other two implementations can take close to 25 seconds per 2-6 symbols word), the Trie search takes only about 1 second. That's close enough for my needs (check if a given password is a combination of symbols from a given dictionary or not).

(See the whole script on http://ideone.com/zQ9Cie)

Results on my local dev VM:

[image]

Results on my AWS EC2 test server:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wether it's very efficient but I guess I would create a loop with an inner loop which goes through the given array containg the symbols.

```
<?php
$aSymbols = array('p', 'pa', 'aw');
$aDatabase = array('paw');
$aMatches = array();

for ($iCounter = 0; $iCounter < count($aSymbols); $iCounter++)
{
    for ($yCounter = 0; $yCounter < count($aSymbols); $yCounter++)
    {
        $sString = $aSymbols[$iCounter].$aSymbols[$yCounter];
        if (in_array($sString, $aDatabase))
        {
            $aMatches[] = $sString;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The if query can be replaced by a regex query, too.

Comment: It is not a valid solution for the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm not looking for a solution for this specific case, but combinations of any number of symbols, any number of times.

Comment: If the symbol array contains p and pp it works. It's rather a quick made sample how it can be done. @elcodedocle Ah, I understand - I am sorry ;)